# Uninstalling Excel add-in using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, add-in

I'm trying to create a MSI installer that installs an Add-In (.xla) into Microsoft Excel (2007 in my case). Installing it goes well. I use a 'Custom Action' that runs this VBScript file:

```
Dim SourceDir
Dim objExcel
Dim objAddin

SourceDir = Session.Property("CustomActionData")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objAddin = objExcel.AddIns.Add(SourceDir & "addin.xla", True)
objAddin.Installed = True
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

I pass the location of the addin to the script using the CustomActionData property. The Add-in is copied to a folder inside 'Program Files', where it will stay until it is uninstalled. This is handled by the installer itself.

The problem is when I use the uninstall script:

```
Dim objExcel
Dim addin
On Error Resume Next

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
For i = 0 To objExcel.Addins.Count
    Set objAddin= objExcel.Addins.item(i)
    If objAddin.Name = "addin.xla" Then
        objAddin.Installed = False
    End If
Next

objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

The addin creates a custom toolbar in Excel u[ installation. The toolbar is not removed upon uninstall, and the entry of the add-in in the 'Add-in' section of Excel's settings isn't either.

Can anyone tell me if these two things can be done programmatically using VBScript?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Almost all collections in VB(A) are 1-based. Your loop goes from zero, and so it'll fail when it tries to access `AddIns(0)`. That's masked by the fact that you have `On Error Resume Next`.

Also, you'll need to explicitly remove the toolbar. Simply removing the add-in won't do that.

I can't say I like the way you're doing it, but it should work at least 50% of the time :-)

Comment: The Add-in is now moved to the 'inactive application add-ins' section. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each Key in Keys
    objReg.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strRegPath & "\" & Key,xlKeys
    For Each xlKey in xlKeys
        if(LCase(xlKey) = "excel") Then
            objReg.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strRegPath & "\" & Key & "\" & xlKey,subKeys

            If(Not ISNULL(subKeys))  Then
                                For Each subKey in subKeys
                    If(lcase(subKey) = "options") Then          'Find Options subKey
                        objReg.EnumValues HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & "\" & Key & "\" & xlKey & "\" & subKey, Values
                        If (Not IsNull(Values)) Then
                                     For Each oValue In Values
                                If (LCase(Left(oValue, 4))="open") Then
                                    objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & "\" & Key & "\" & xlKey & "\" & subKey & "\", oValue, sTempValue
                                    If(Not XLAddinRemove(sTempValue)) Then

                                                                                If(aOpenKeyVals(0)<>"") Then
                                            Redim Preserve aOpenKeyVals(UBound(aOpenKeyVals)+1)
                                        End If
                                        aOpenKeyVals(UBound(aOpenKeyVals))=sTempValue
                                                                        End If
                                    objReg.DeleteValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & "\" & Key & "\" & xlKey & "\" & subKey, oValue
                                End If
                            Next
                            For iOLoop = 0 To UBound(aOpenKeyVals)
                                If(iOLoop>0) Then sOpenName = "OPEN" & iOLoop
                                If aOpenKeyVals(iOLoop) <> "" Then
                                                                  objReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & "\" & Key & "\" & xlKey & "\" & subKey, sOpenName, aOpenKeyVals(iOLoop)
                                                                End If 
                            Next

                            sOpenName="OPEN"
                            Redim aOpenKeyVals (0)
                            aOpenKeyVals (0)=""
                        End If
                    End If
                 Next
            End If
          End If
    Next
Next
```